# How to use .Include() with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm implementing AutoMapper in my app to have different views for different needs. Until now I've more or less just used the DomainModel.

But when I use AutoMapper for my ViewModel, how do I then .Include() related data?

Startup.cs:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(AutoMapperProfiles));
```

AutoMapperProfiles.cs:

```
public class AutoMapperProfiles : Profile
{

    public AutoMapperProfiles()
    {

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Product, ProductVM>();
        });

        Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

    }

}
```

My model:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
}

public class ProductVM
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}

public class ProductCategory
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name ( get; set; }
}
```

OnGet:

```
var products = await _dbContext.Products.ProjectTo<ProductVM>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).Include(x => x.ProductCategory).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: With ProjectTo, you don't need Include, everything your mapping needs is fetched by default.

Comment: This seems like the most convenient way. VS gives me no errors, but when I run the code in the browser I get: `InvalidOperationException: Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.`

Comment: I fixed it by injecting IConfigurationProvider. :) Please mark your comment as an answer.

Comment: One last question: is it correct, that with AutoMapper all data from the database table is loaded and the filtering is done afterwards? If true, isn't that a big issue performance-wise?

Comment: No. See http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: Well, one more question: after going with ProjectTo I get the relationships right, but the values are null. Please see updated question.

Comment: Call AssertConfigurationIsValid and do spend some time reading the docs, because it seems to me that you understand very little about AM.

Comment: I did. And it confirms what I already know: *Unmapped properties: ProductCategory*

Comment: And why do you think that is?

Comment: Well, if I knew that... You told me at first to use ProjectTo and leave the rest to AutoMapper. Reading the docs - which I did a lot along with other resources - the .ForMember() handles relations, but that don't seems to do anything for me.

Comment: Is it really so hard for you to point out for me what I'm doing wrong, so that I can learn from that? My ProductVM works and have data, but ProductVM.ProductCategory.Name is null.

Comment: It seems to me like you're not really willing to put in the effort to understand things. Or maybe I don't understand your question. But I look at your code and I don't see how anybody would expect that to work. Maybe I'm missing smth myself.

Comment: I'm obviously missing something in understanding this, but I've read and read and read but haven't found anything useful. That's maybe because I'm stupid or because I don't know what to look for. I've updated my question to include all the relevant parts. If you see anything that can solve my issue, please let me know.

Comment: It works if I put the properties back in the Product class. I just hoped to keep it clean.

Comment: It can work without that, but it's a lot more complicated because then you need the MapFrom and you need to fetch the data yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if your names match exactly:

```
CreateMap<Product, ProductVM>().ForMember(p => p.Tags, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: Thanks, Leon. I found ProjectTo to be more convenient. :)